# Android-Studio new project

Tags: android, android-studio

When I create a new project in Android-Studio , all was perfect but before launching it take a lot of time to download from maven repository , can I download of this dependencies manually and add it to Android Studio .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have repositories on the local file system. This works for both Maven and Ivy repositories.

Example 8.7. Usage of a local Ivy directory

```
build.gradle
repositories {
    ivy {
         // URL can refer to a local directory
    url "../local-repo"
    }
}
```

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Comment: So gradle can work without any problem with maven repository , or it needs a specific repository....

Answer (score 0):

This is one time procedure. All downloaded content will be saved for future use. You can achieve same with manual download with mvn client. But it will same file from same servers at same speed. So you wont get any benefit from this.

Comment: if I use IDM to download all jars required it will a best , but android-studio don't give any information about size or where I put jars in local file...